# How to add an alert if the numericupdown is greater than the available stock in the inventory

Tags: c#, sql

I've been trying to figure out how can I add an alert if the value of the numericupdown encoded by the user on c# is greater than the amount of stocks in the inventory based on the database.

Answer (score 0):

In `ValueChanged` event handler Check your stock and then you add alert for user.
ValueChanged event is fired when the value of a NumericUpDown control is changed, To add this property event handler, you go to Events window and double click on the ValueChanged event.

**Show Alert**

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('we do not have enough “item” in stock to fulfil your order')", true);
```

Comment: i dont understand :(

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for me is to add a **max value** for your **numericupdown input**.
You can do it by reading the ***stock quantity*** and then add ***max attribut in the input***, so the user cannot choose a number bigger than the max (stock quantity).
**Nb:** But it's better also to add a validation in your back-end, to compare numericupdown input with stock quantity.

To show the alert, i don't know what you're using in C#, for example if you're using Windows application, you can do it by adding: MessageBox.Show and pass you parameters :

- Message box alert type
- Message box title
- Message box body..etc

Comment: Hi! Can you show me an example code for this one on how can I reference my database on the alert? btw, I'm using the MessageBox for the alert. 

`if(numericupdown > ----(column in database)){ Messagebox.Show()("alert")}`.